# Item Description on a Feature Class Not Appearing on a Published Feature Access Service via ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, metadata

I have a feature class in an SDE where metadata has been loaded via the 'Load XML Recordset Document' option of the feature class. When viewing the item description
of the feature class, the metadata appears (which is what I want), such as:

[image]

After I publish the feature class as a Feature Access Service via ArcGIS Server, then view the item description of the feature class from the service. The metadata does not appear, such as:

[image]

Any thoughts to have item description on the feature class appear on the Feature Access service?

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1, ArcGIS Server 10.3.1, and a SQL Server SDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted ESRI, this issue is a bug.

BUG-000091609:Metadata from a Feature Class Does not Carry over to Feature Service